# Is the google doc doesn't need the resourcekey?

Tags: google-drive-api

Hello I'm trying to getting resourcekey with google drive api
I already updated the security what you guys recommended

But stil I can't get the resourceKey from files's get api with fileId
So I wanna check that the google doc like Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Form doesn't need the resourceKey for shared link such as  exportLinks, webContentLink, and webViewLink
and also When I use the google drive files's get method, Is it correct that the file kind of google doc has the resourceKey?

I attach the response of my google spreadsheet files metadata
please check the follow and teach me what i wrong or missed

```
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4",
 "name": "CSS_v1_lpNnyJfGaiAo_6",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ],
 "version": "8",
 "webViewLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4/edit?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "hasThumbnail": true,
 "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&v=2&s=AMedNnoAAAAAYSRx8dDKAoD1Q16M021MvQjUnGn3rCDS&sz=s220",
 "thumbnailVersion": "2",
 "viewedByMe": true,
 "viewedByMeTime": "2021-04-08T08:51:13.861Z",
 "createdTime": "2021-04-08T08:45:54.117Z",
 "modifiedTime": "2021-04-08T08:46:04.434Z",
 "modifiedByMe": false,
 "sharedWithMeTime": "2021-04-08T08:51:13.861Z",
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "me": false,
   "permissionId": "08922093982962563488",
   "emailAddress": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "me": false,
  "permissionId": "08922093982962563488",
  "emailAddress": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
 },
 "shared": true,
 "ownedByMe": false,
 "capabilities": {
  "canAddChildren": false,
  "canAddMyDriveParent": false,
  "canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
  "canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled": false,
  "canChangeViewersCanCopyContent": false,
  "canComment": true,
  "canCopy": true,
  "canDelete": false,
  "canDownload": true,
  "canEdit": true,
  "canListChildren": false,
  "canModifyContent": true,
  "canMoveChildrenWithinDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemOutOfDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemWithinDrive": true,
  "canReadRevisions": true,
  "canRemoveChildren": false,
  "canRemoveMyDriveParent": true,
  "canRename": true,
  "canShare": true,
  "canTrash": false,
  "canUntrash": false
 },
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
 "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "permissions": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "anyoneWithLink",
   "type": "anyone",
   "role": "writer",
   "allowFileDiscovery": false
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "08922093982962563488",
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "role": "owner",
   "displayName": "realsearch@realsearch-1611815321770.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "deleted": false
  }
 ],
 "permissionIds": [
  "anyoneWithLink",
  "08922093982962563488"
 ],
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
 "isAppAuthorized": false,
 "exportLinks": {
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=ods",
  "text/tab-separated-values": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=tsv",
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=pdf",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=xlsx",
  "text/csv": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=csv",
  "application/zip": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=zip",
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1X8LSm3IuA90EDGg3DRQ39cs87OoQYDjxrJwoxq0bPx4&exportFormat=ods"
 },
 "linkShareMetadata": {
  "securityUpdateEligible": false,
  "securityUpdateEnabled": true
 }
}
```

Comment: No it's different question did you read my question?? i ask ythat the google doc has resourceKey or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all files are impacted by this security update. When I tried to make changes to my application I too had this issue where the meta data of a file does not show the resourceKey when the google drive documentation clearly says that its supposed to be there. The problem with me was that I assumed all the files would have resourceKey, I found out that this in fact was not true. Only some files in my google drive has resoucekey.

You can find which files are being impacted by this security update by searching

```
is:security_update_applied
```

on the google drive search field.
[image]

If you try and fetch the metadata for those files you can find the resource key at the bottom as the documentations states.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning Monday, September 13, 2021, Google will begin enforcing a security update to Google Drive. Users like you who own or manage impacted files will be notified about the affected files beginning Monday, July 26, 2021.

This security update adds a resource key that makes sharing links from Google Drive files more secure. When file links are updated, users may receive new file access requests. Those who do not have accessed to the files before the update will have to use URLs containing resource keys to access the files.

To avoid broken links, users should update Google Drive links on their websites and shared resources before September 13.

## Update Impacts Developers

Affected items are those that have a Drive File API permission with type=domain or `type=anyone` where `withLink=true` [(v2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions) or `allowFileDiscovery=false` [(v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).

In addition to the item ID, applications may need a resource key to access files. Use [Google’s Developer resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys) to learn more about how this update will impact your projects.

## Is the google doc doesn't need the resourcekey?

Only you can decide if your files and the permissions they currently have require that you use the resource key or not.

## Find your impacted files

[Security update for Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743?hl=en)

Comment: it is almost a copy-paste from emails Google sent to us, but can you advice something more specific what to do exactly? Hate Google that something that already worked - now broken and even more - there is no any respectful advices how to fix it (only Google-style manuals for everybody, and so, for no one exactly)

Comment: @okliv at the time of writing this answer we had very limited information.  I have been trying to keep the answer updated.  As your question is a very good place to keep these things centralized rather than having multiple questions on the same topic.